# jsreport template dynamic generate 2D Barcode

Tags: jsreport

I am a new user for JSReport, I want to build a template for phantomjs PDF that include a 2D Barcode, however, 2D Barcode content generate dynamically. Could anyone can guild? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends how you want to generate the barcode image.
One option is to use external (free) service which does this for you, then you just need to insert html image with proper url

```
<img src='https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=ABCDEFG&style=197&type=C128B&width=180&height=50&xres=1&font=3'/>
```

You would typically fill the code using handlebars in jsreport like this

```
<img src='https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code={{code}}&style=197&type=C128B&width=180&height=50&xres=1&font=3'/>
```

**Playground demo**
https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/FnOXpvbt

Another option is using an npm module that can render the barcodes serverside like the [bwip-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bwip-js).

**Playground demo**
https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/EYFN1vXc

Comment: I tried to make same and follow to your suggestion, but there is no barcode image.

Comment: I updated the demo links and also added an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for give me some key point. I also found below script can generate 2D barcode also.

*< img id='barcode' 
            src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&size=100x100" 
            alt="" 
            title="HELLO" 
            width="100" 
            height="100" />*

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question.
I need this function but the url does not work
Google has a solution

https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes

```
<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl={{rowinfo.qrCode}}&chs=200x200&choe=UTF-8'/>
```